# Castle ActiveRecord - Enable Lazy Loading in Medium Trust

Tags: nhibernate, activerecord, castle

I have a MVC3 application running in a Medium Trust Server, that use Castle ActiveRecord, but if I enable the Lazy Loading, a yellow sreen Security Exception is showed to me. If I disable the Lazy Loading, everything works.

There is a way to use Lazy Loading in a Medium Trust Server with Castle.Core version 3 and nHibernate 3.1.0.4000?

Sorry for my english and thanks.

Update:

In my searches on Google, I found this options:

**Pre-Generate Lazy Loading Proxies**

http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/pre-generate-lazy-loading-proxies.aspx

I tried, but looks like that don't work with Caste.Core 3 and nHibernate 3.1. I'm wrong?

Looks like this option dont receive updates for a long time and this is bad.

**New adventures under medium trust**

http://blogs.taiga.nl/martijn/2009/06/24/new-adventures-under-medium-trust/

In Castle DynamicProxy topic, I found:

"The solution was a simple one: DynamicProxy calls AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule and used the overload that generates debug symbols. Changing that to not generate the debug symbols anymore made it work under medium trust!"

I open source of Castle.Core and I found AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule in ModuleScope.cs (Castle.Core\DynamicProxy), and in calls its already set false to generate debug symbols.

Answer (score 0):

When I had a similar problem I had to download the castle source and set `AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers` and then recompiled.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Thomas! I did this, but I think that don't have relation with Lazy Loading. My only problem is enable Lazy and don't run Castle in Medium Trust (this I already did doing what you did). Thanks for the help.

Comment: If I understand for Lazy Loading Castle.Core is emmiting IL code for proxy generation. Thats why in medium trust it doesn't work. But maybe someone else knows better then me how to overcome this limitation. I would be interested to hear about

Comment: Thomas, I put in my question two options to enable lazy loading in medium trust that I found in Google. What do you think about the options?